# How can I order the DOM in masonry?

Tags: javascript, layout, jquery-masonry, masonry, reflow

How can I order the DOM in masonry?

here is my code, http://jsbin.com/niqasiqisi/1/edit?html,css,output

In this I want to order the input elements like below

[1]|[4]
[2]|[5]
[3]|[6]

if I remove the [2] the [3] should take the place of [2] and [4] should come below. How can I create a layout like this using masonry. What are the feature to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the original jQuery Masonry, there's very little you can do to preserve order.  [Take a look at the API documentation](http://masonry.desandro.com/options.html), you won't see order mentioned once.  There's a reason -- it's built to most effectively sort items for layout efficiency, at the expense of order.  You're jamming the most things in the tightest space.

Try another plugin, I suggest Isotope by the same author.  It has [several options](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/options.html#sortascending) for ordering.